# Migrating Hibernate 3.6 to Hibernate 5.2.3 Fail to process type argument in a generic delcaration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

First of all 
I am trying to upgrade Hibernate 3.6 to 5.2.3, first met problem with second level cache, it used to be

```
configuration.setProperty(Environment.CACHE_PROVIDER,"org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider");
```

since it does not has CACH_PROVIDER in hibernate 5, so I changed it to `config.setProperty(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY,"org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");`

dont know if this is related, Here is the stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Fail to process type argument in a generic declaration. Member : com.rtrms.application.view.filter.CollectionFilter#filters Type: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.getClassFromGenericArgument(AttributeFactory.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:760)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:541)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.rtrms.persistence.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryTest.buildSessionFactory(HibernateRepositoryTest.java:583)
    at com.rtrms.persistence.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryTest.setUp(HibernateRepositoryTest.java:170)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Another thing is, since I'm upgrade from hibernate 3 to hibernate 5, it seems there is not a good tutorial for the migration process since it made so many changes, do I have to migrade from hibernate 3 to 4, then 4 to 5? or any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you've not already fixed this, I'd recommend migrating incrementally. There are a lot of new changes in Hibernate 4 especially with their new Integrator mechanism if you use Event listeners. We've just gone through this process, described in more detail here: https://otter606.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/migrating-a-spring-mvc-webapp-from-hibernate-3-to-hibernate-5/

Answer (score 0):

Moving from 5.1.2.Final to 5.2.3 I get the "WildcardTypeImpl" error, so maybe try and move to 5.1.2 until the 5.2 branch is fixed?